# Typedef enum to string in C

Tags: string, enums, typedef

I have error typedefs as follows.

```
typedef enum {  Connection_Error
    , Parity_Error
    , Data_Read_Error 
     } error_t;
```

And I have a function returning the "error_t". I would like to change the enum to string (preferably without using **switch(case)**).

Eg.

```
char str[20];
str = function_to_convert_to_string (error_t);
```

Something like that.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C language does not have any built-in provision for storing symbol-names as strings in the output binary program (unlike Java and C# which have the `.ToString()` method) so you must manually do this in your code - fortunately it's made easier with the preprocessor's ability to convert symbols to string-literals ("stringification").

Note that `typedef enum { ... } name` is unnecessary, and avoid using `_t` as a suffix as it is reserved by the POSIX specifications.

Try this:

```
enum errorType {
    Connection_Error,
    Parity_Error,
    Data_Read_Error
};

#define ERRMSG( ARG ) \
case ARG: \
    return "Error: " #ARG ".";

char* getErrorMessage(errorType e) {
    switch(e) {
        ERRMSG( Connection_Error )
        ERRMSG( Parity_Error )
        ERRMSG( Data_Read_Error )
        default: exit(1); // or some other error handler
    }
}
```

Note how you see the enum is manually listed twice in code: first in the `enum` definition, and again in the `switch` block. For small enums this is fine, but if your enum list is large or changes frequently you'll want to adopt a DRY approach. You can simplify it by listing all of the enums in their own text file, like so:

#### ErrorTypeEnum.inc

```
 ENTRY( Connection_Error )
 ENTRY( Parity_Error )
 ENTRY( Data_Read_Error )
```

#### ErrorTypeEnum.h

```
 #define ENTRY(NAME) NAME,
 enum errorType {
 #include "ErrorTypeEnum.inc"
     _Last
 }
 #undef ENTRY
```

The `_Last` entry is needed because of the trailing comma, also provides a means to get the count f elements because `_Last` will have a numeric value equal to the last `ENTRY` + 1.

#### ErrorTypeEnum.c

```
char* getErrorMessage(errorType e) {
    switch(e) {
#define ENTRY(NAME) case NAME: return "Error: " #NAME ".";
#include "ErrorTypeEnum.inc"
        default: exit(1); // or some other error handler
#undef
    }
}
```

#### Further

You can expand upon this by adding other values to the ENTRY macro, such as custom human-readable error messages (instead of using stringification). That is an exercise left up to the reader :)